# PHP MySQL get dates and split data into JSON for each month

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have an `MySQL`-database with a table which contains a lot of events, e.g concerts. The structure of the table is pretty simple:

```
id (int, 11, pk , ai)
event_name (varchar, 255)
event_location (varchar, 255)
event_date (date)
```

Now, for display purpose on the frontend, I would like to show the events in some kind of "month overview", like:

```
January
- event blabla  10/01/17
- event thisandthat  17/01/17

February
- event something 05/02/17
- event another something 13/02/17

...etc etc
```

So I was thinking about how to achieve this. Should I create another table and give any month an ID, and also add an "month_id" field in the events-table?

I would like to do some `json_encode` so that in the end I will have an `JSON`-array with objects which has all the data.

Any suggestions? Or even better: any examples?

** UPDATE **

My desired result should look something like this:

```
[{
    "January": [{
            "event_name": "blabla",
            "event_location" : "somewhere",
            "event_date": "2017-01-10" 
        },
        {
            "event_name": "blabla",
            "event_location" : "somewhere",
            "event_date": "2017-01-17"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "February": [{
            "event_name": "blabla",
            "event_location" : "somewhere",
            "event_date": "2017-02-10"
        },
        {
            "event_name": "blabla",
            "event_location" : "somewhere",
            "event_date": "2017-02-17"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "March": [{
            "event_name": "blabla",
            "event_location" : "somewhere",
            "event_date": "2017-03-10"
        },
        {
            "event_name": "blabla",
            "event_location" : "somewhere",
            "event_date": "2017-03-17"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: You can ORDER BY event_date but you would need `YYYY-MM-DD` format, which is recommended.

Comment: There are a thousand ways to do that, I would suggest to sort by date, so when you stream in the results, you can say the month and use it in the structure you create the JSON from accordingly (group by month).

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql="SELECT MONTH(event_date) event_month, * FROM events ORDER BY event_date";
```

Then enter in a foreach loop with results comparing if event_month is null (first loop) or the same of the previous loop. If it is the same your into the month events subset otherwise you're starting a new month.

```
$currentmonth=null;
for($row in $rows){
    if($row["event_month"]!=$currentmonth){
        echo "Month ".$row["event_month"];
        $row["event_month"]=$currentmonth;      
    }
    echo "\tevent ".$row["event_name"];
}
```

Comment: As one month comes after the other for any date, ordering by `event_date` is enough (you can spare applying the MONTH function in the ORDER BY clause).

Comment: And another hint: If you create the comparison value from the result rows within the loops based on column `event_date`, you can create array keys and create a JSON response very easily that also works for dates in different years. That would also solve to divide data-processing from outpur, which costs a bit of memory but will make it overall a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and extract the month in your query, something like this

```
SELECT event_name, event_location, event_date,
       DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y - %M') AS event_month
WHERE ...
ORDER BY event_date
```

Whatever format works for you. Including the year may or may not be useful, depending on what you're doing with it. If you don't need the year included, you can just use MONTH or MONTHNAME instead.

Then group by that as you fetch the rows from your query result.

```
<?php

while ($row = $stmt->yourFavoriteFetchMethod()) {
    $result[$row->event_month][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: The query adds that, but the grouping should be done with `$result[$row->event_month][] = $row;`. Is that not working for you?